# Sufficient condition for simple graph isomorphism?

Tags: graphs

Say I have two simple graphs, $A$ and $B$

- In $A$, I know:

  - one node has 3 nodes at distance of 1, 4 nodes at distance 2, etc.
  - one node has 4 nodes at distance of 1, 1 nodes at distance 2, etc.
  - etc.
- In $B$, I know:

  - one node has 3 nodes at distance of 1, 4 nodes at distance 2, etc.
  - one node has 4 nodes at distance of 1, 1 nodes at distance 2, etc.
  - etc.

Can I derive that graph $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic to each other? Or is there a counter-example where two graphs look the same from this distance point of view, but are not isomorphic?

It is a necessary condition, so if these simple graphs are isomorphic, they will share these distances. I am wondering if this is a sufficient condition as well.

Comment: I have indeed corrected the title and added a clarification with what is meant by geodesic distance.

Comment: The complexity of graph isomorphism is a famous open problem in computer science and if your condition were sufficient, that would immediately give a simple polynomial-time algorithm. It's very unlikely that everybody would have missed such a simple algorithm, if one existed.

Comment: DRs comment does not formalize this single instance to something more general. a more general way/ algorithm would seem to involve computing a "distance matrix" for the graph.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two non-isomorphic graphs with 16 vertices in which each vertex has 6 neighbors and 9 vertices at distance 2: the [Shrikhande graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrikhande_graph) and the $4\times 4$ [rook's graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph).

Comment: See also _[strongly regular graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_regular_graph)_, which both of these happen to be.

Comment: Is the OP's condition sufficient for graphs with less than 16 vertices, then?

Comment: @BeeOnRope I don't find this a terribly interesting question.

Comment: Sorry (I guess?), but It is interesting for me. For example, I want to quickly compute isomorphism groups for graphs for limited _n_, generally n < 15. So such a shortcut would be useful. In any case, the strength of stackexchange is  that it only takes one person to find something interesting to reply!